# Is it possible to deploy local linked template via New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to specify linked template deployment file somehow in `New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet without specifying external URL, just like you can do with `-TemplateFile` parameter locally

Comment: Gregory - I'm interested in your scenario... i.e. why are you trying to (or want to) deploy from local source?

Comment: Same reason why you do it in with main template, fast development cycle and ease of deployment within environment. That is not need to have publicly hosted URI specified and needed to be secured.

Comment: Have you tried the scripts available for staging?  (wondering about your feedback on those as well)

Comment: What do you mean scripts available for staging? I don't want to upload scripts to any public/private resource at all, I want all of them to stay on my local machine, so if I debug it all I need to do is to change it locally and not upload each time, it works very well with root template

Comment: Staging artifacts is a common pattern for deployments - the quickstart repo has a few scripts that do the work... https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 or https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/az-group-deploy.sh -- the reason it works without for main template is everything is loaded into a single PUT request by the tools.  That doesn't scale for larger deployments, binaries, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of ability to upload and stage those. I really wanted an option to continue working with local file with no prestaging neccessary for multiple reasons above.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying... it's unlikely you'll ever see that since ARM will not have access to your local machine.  We've been thinking of a packaging format for deployments (e.g. Managed Apps) but that will still require staging the package (since ARM will not be able to access the local machine).

Comment: How does it to with main template then? Why can not you just ZIP content and send it over as  binary format in JSON for example?

Comment: Main template is sent in the JSON body...  ZIP & send isn't that much different than what's happening today - all the artifacts are sent, they're just stored in storage that the user owns not ARM.  The user needs access to that storage for things like debugging, audit, rollback.

Comment: Right now if you don't use nested templates you can do entire deployment with no requirements of having storage account, sastokens etc, also super easy to make changes and debug deployments. I assumed if you ZIP nested deployment and put in in main JSON body it will accomplish the same convenience with no requirement to upload to storage account first and provide the same benefits deployments with no staging artficats provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because Azure has to be able to download it. No real workarounds. Upload and deploy with script